# Subclass/Child class

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I had this class and subclass :

> class Range:

```
def __init__(self, start, end):
    self.setStart(start)
    self.setEnd(end)
def getStart(self):
    return self.start

def setStart(self, s):
    self.start = s
def getEnd(self):
    return self.end
def setEnd(self, e):
    self.end = e
def getLength(self):
    return len(range(self.start, self.end))
def overlaps(self, r):
    if (r.getStart() < self.getEnd() and r.getEnd() >= self.getEnd()) or \
       (self.getStart() < r.getEnd() and self.getEnd() >= r.getEnd()) or \
       (self.getStart() >= r.getStart() and self.getEnd() <= r.getEnd()) or \
       (r.getStart() >= self.getStart() and r.getEnd() <= self.getEnd()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

> class DNAFeature(Range):
>
> ```
>    def __init__(self, start, end):
>             self.setStart(start)
>             self.setEnd(end)
>             self.strand = none
>             self.sequencename = none
>    def getSeqName(self, s):
>             return self.SeqName
>    def setSeqName(self, s):
>             self.sequencename = s
>    def getStrand(self):
>             if self.SeqName == 'plus':
>                     return 1
>             elif self.SeqName == 'minus':
>                     return -1
>             else:
>                     return 0
>    def setStrand(self, s):
>             self.strand = s
> ```

And here is what I have to do:
Create  a  new  class –  GeneModel ‐  that  contains  a  group  of  DNAFeature  objects  representing  exons  and  is  a  child  class  of  DNAFeature.  It  should  implement  the  following  methods:    
getFeats()  – returns  a  list  of  DNAFeature  objects, sorted  by  start  position 
addFeat(feat) –  accepts  a  DNAFeature  feat  and  adds  it  to  its  internal  group  of  DNAFeature  objects 
setTranslStart(i) –  accepts  a  non‐negative  int, sets  the  start  position  of  the  initiating  ATG  codon 
getTranslStart() – returns  an  int,  the  start  position  of  the  initiating  ATG  codon 
setTranslStop(i) –  accepts  a  positive  int, sets  the  end  position  for  the  stop  codon 
getTranslStop() –  returns  an  int, the  end  position  for  the  stop  codon 
setDisplayId(s)  – sets  the  name  of  the  gene  model;  s  is  a  string 
getDisplayId() –  return  the  name  of  the  gene  model,  returns  a  string, e.g., AT1G10555.1    GeneModel  should  raise  appropriate  ValueError  and  TypeError  exceptions  when  users  pass  incorrect  types  and  values  to  constructors  and  “set”  methods.

I have tried to write whatever comes to my mind, and read the books as well as searching the way to put codes together, but I am so new to programming and hardly can understand how to write the codes correctly. To be honest, this is the first time I ever do a programming class. So if I make any funny mistake in my codes, please forgive me. I haven't finish my codes yet and still reading the books to see where I am doing wrong and right with my codes. However, I really need your help to guide me to the right path. Thank you guys very much. Below is my codes:

> class GeneModel(DNAFeature):
>
> ```
>    def __init__(self, translstart, translend, displayid):
>             self.setTranslStart(translstart)
>             self.setTranslStop(translend)
>             setDisplayId(displayid)
>    def getFeats():
>             result = []
>             sort.self.getStart()
>             return result
>    def addFeat(feat):
>             self.addFeat = feat
>             return self.getStart+self.getEnd
>    def setTranslStart(i):
>             self.translstart = self.setStart
>             self.translstart = non-negative int
>    def getTranslStart():
>             return self.translstart
>    def setTranslStop(i):
>             self.translend = self.setEnd
>             self.translend = "+" int
>    def getTranslStop():
>             return self.translend
>    def setDisplayId(s):
>             self.displayid = re.compile('r'\AT1G[0-9]{5,5}\.[0-9]{,1}, IGNORECASE')
>    def getDisplayId():
>             return self.displayid
> ```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your model here. Is GeneModel supposed to contain a set of DNAFeature instances or is GeneModel a subclass of DNAFeature. It makes a big difference as to how you write your code.

Comment: yes, it is, GeneModel is a child class of DNAFeature, I really sorry about my codes, I just dont know how to do it right, trying to read through the books...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the name of the gene model is. I think it's subject specific, but I think this will work for you:

```
class GenoModel(DNAFeature):

    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.setStart(start)
        self.setEnd(end)
        self.strand = None
        self.sequencename = None
        self.exons = []
        self.translStart = None
        self.translStop = None
        self.displayId = None

    def getFeats(self):
        self.exons.sort(cmp=self.start)
        return self.exons

    def addFeat(self, f):

        if type(f) == DNAFeature:
            self.exons.append(f)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Cannot add feature as it is not of type DNAFeature")

    def setTranslStart(self, i):

        if type(i) != int:
            raise TypeError("Cannot set translStart as it is not of type int")
        elif i < 0:
            raise ValueError("Cannot set tanslStart to a negative int")
        else:
            self.translStart = i

    def getTranslStart(self):
        return self.translStart

    def setTranslStop(self, i):

        if type(i) != int:
            raise TypeError("Cannot set translStop as it is not of type int")
        elif i <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Cannot set tanslStop to anything less than 1")
        else:
            self.translStop = i

    def getTranslStop(self):
        return self.translStop

    def setDisplayId(self, s):

        if type(s) != str:
            raise TypeError("Cannot set desiplayId as it is not of type string")
        else:
            self.displayId = s

    def getDisplayId(self):
        return self.displayId
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it because GeneModel is subclass of DNAFeature which was a subclass of Range, that in the def __init__ it will have to be the 3 argument that we define in Range which is self, start and end? Is that right? I just curious, thanks inspector

Comment: Yes, but more importantly, if you didn't define an init here, GeneModel by default will take DNAFeature's init.

Comment: I see, one more question inspector, what is it mean by using != for ex: if type(s) !=str: or type(i) !=int: ? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure that you are aware that "==" tests for equality. "!=" is the opposite of that. It tests for inequality. It's like saying "not ==". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

First, a little bit of cleanup. I'm not completely convinced that your original class, DNAFeature, is actually correct. DNAFeature seems to be inheriting from some other class, named Range, that we're missing here so if you have that code please offer it as well. In that original class, you need to define the variable SeqName (also, its preferable to keep variables lower-cased) since otherwise self.SeqName will be meaningless. Additionally, unless they're inherited from the Range class, you should also define the methods "setStart" and "setEnd". You're getter should not any additional variables, so feel free to change it to "def getSeqName(self)" instead of adding "s". I'm not sure what else your code is really supposed to do, so I'll hold any further comment.

Additionally, though you stated otherwise in your comment, I have to believe from the naming conventions (and what little I remember from bio) that you actually want GeneModel to be a container for a set of DNAFeature instances. That's different from GeneModel subclassing DNAFeature. If I'm right, then you can try:

```
class GeneModel(object):

    def __init__(dnafeatures):
        self.dnafeatures = dnafeatures

    def get_features(self):
        return self.dnafeatures

    def add_feature(self, feature):
        self.dnafeatures.append(feature)
```

Here *dnafeatures* would just be a list of dnafeature instances. This would then allow you to write methods to access these features and do whatever fun stuff you need to do.

My advice would be to make sure your DNAFeature class is correct and that your model of how you want your problem solved (in terms of what your classes do) and try asking again when its a little clearer. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have update my original class Range, for some reason not sure why its doesn't look perfectly between the class Range line and the next line. I am not sure if the subclass DNAFeature is correct as I dont have any test file to test it. But hope you can help me to figure out with the original class. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for updating when your Range class. It still looks like you need to add SeqName to DNAFeatures. Otherwise, I believe that you can still take my skeleton GeneModel class and add methods as you see fit.  As you learn python, you'll figure out the more pythonic ways of doing things (like doing (self.end-self.start) instead of len(range(self.start, self.end)) but hopefully that'll start you off.

Comment: I see, I'll tried it, thanks jlv a lot, your guide help me a lot. Thanks again